# JS Height of Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a fixed navbar with Bootstrap. Problem is, sometimes it overlaps the title and other content on my pages.

I have a vid with a manual margin to try and fix this problem, but the navbar height constantly changes if I add an announcement to it and hence it either overlaps too much or there is a large gap between the navbar and content.

```
<div class="sep" id="separator" style="padding-top:60px">
```

The div above works but isn't accurate, is there a way that when the page is loaded I could get the entire height of my navbar and then put that height into the separator div so it would have a custom padding-top every time?

Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Post your code that you're having problems with.

Comment: You really should post your code. Otherwise your question will get downvoted a lot. Also, related to your question. Let's say I advice you to use AJAX. The answer is exactly like your question. Do you like it?

Comment: @lonut That'd be useless, there is no code to show because it changes with PHP, not the HTML or CSS.

Comment: You said you use Bootstrap. How is that related with PHP? Bootstrap is HTML, CSS and JS/jQuery. Your comment in the answer bellow says you want to avoid JS. How are you suppose to get the height with PHP?!

Comment: It needs to be passed to a PHP variable.

Comment: Again, use AJAX. That simple. I suggest you start learning because it seems you don't have any knowledge about JS. And without knowing, how are you suppose to do things?!

Comment: Question fixed to be more specific, I'm a back-end developer, I'm just faced with this predicament today.

Answer (score 0):

I'm  a bit confused on the question here, but I think (?) this is what you are looking for. Just change margin-top to something different

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    var d = $('#test');
    var h = d.height();        
    d.css('margin-top', 100);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This seems like it'll work, but I hardly know JS and try to avoid it. I'm more back-end. I'll try to integrate it now.

Comment: I edited it to make it tad simpler for you then. Just change #test to #whateverIDtheDivHas, and margin-top to the css property you want to change

Comment: I gave a bad explanation. The nav has a height that is constantly changing when the announcement bar is added to it, right after the body I have a div with the ID of "separator" - it has a manually fixed padding to stop the nav bar overlapping but often it creates too much or too little space, so I need this padding to change and be equal to the total height of the navigation bar.

Comment: because adding a margin or padding to the actual navigation bar doesn't work, it has to be a seperate div.